# Need Help: SQL Server Instance Name Error on Plesk Hosting Server

Tags: .net, sql-server, web-hosting, plesk

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) TESTS FAILED!

[Please see the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xC1fv.png)

How can I solve this problem and also tell me how to upload my ASP.NET MVC ( 4.5 version) on this server because I am new to this hosting server.

Comment: Please help me I am struck

Answer (score 0):

Check SQL server instance name it should be something like:

- .\SQLSERVER
- .\MSSQLSERVER2012
- .\MSSQLSERVER2014

You can find it at Plesk database page:

[image: Plesk Microsoft SQL server connection]

Plesk web deploy settings:

[image: Plesk web deploy IIS]

[image]

This button give you file with FTP settings to your publish tool with content like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<publishData><publishProfile profileName="domain.tld - Web Deploy" publishMethod="MSDeploy" publishUrl="domain.tld" msdeploySite="domain.tld" userName="ftp1" destinationAppUrl="http://domain.tld" controlPanelLink="http://10.52.58.17:8880"/></publishData>
```

Comment: Thanks @OlegNeumyvakin, Now the message is: Success: Connection established. Disconnecting from server. TESTS COMPLETED SUCCESSFULLY!.. Please tell me the  how to show my  my ASP .NET  MVC site with SQL database on Plesk after the connection establishment.

Comment: Well it depend of how you developing your application, Plesk provides you FTP access to upload your application files on server. I think you need to search or create separate question about deploying application on shared hosting.

Comment: @MuhammadAmir Plesk also can provides file with Web Deploy publishing settings, but it's just FTP settings to your web site. Here the nice guide: http://windowswebhostingreview.com/how-to-publish-using-web-deploy-with-plesk-control-panel/

Comment: Thank you so much @OlegNeumyvakin, this helped me !